# ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found

Tags: oracle, database-link

I have created a db link `AM_ADMIN` through SQL Developer:

[image]

I am trying to check if it is a valid database link. When I test it from the SQL Developer wizard it is successful. But when I use the below command:

```
SELECT * FROM dual@AM_ADMIN
```

I'm getting the error:

> ORA-02019: connection description for remote database not found

How can I rectify this error?

Comment: Have you tried tnsping to the entry referenced on your db link?

Comment: i tried tnsping on host name and service name both.
for service name it was 1 ms for host name i got the error 
ORA-12504, TNS:listener was not given the SID in CONNECT_DATA
  ping:-1ms
But i guess it is as expected isn't it?

Comment: How did you create the database link, and how are you testing it - what exactly 'shows successfully'? Are you creating it and running this query as different users? Does your `sqlnet.ora` have `names.default_domain` set? (Or are you maybe confusing DB links and TNS aliases?)

Comment: @Alex i have created the db link via sql developer console (attached in question).
when i am testing from console itself by clicking on test db link , it shows db link has been successfully tested.
i am running it from same user with the console itself

Comment: @sstan i am using sqldeveloper to run tnsping and select statement.

Comment: `tnsping` isn't relevant here; your DB link isn't using a TNS alias. The error  means it isn't recognising the DB link name. One reason for that is because it may need to be qualified, e.g. `dual@am_admin.world`.

Comment: The link you created isn't public.  'select * from user_db_links' and verify you see the link listed.  If not, you probably created under a different user's account?

Answer (score 4):

This error will occur when a database link is not made PUBLIC, and the user who created the link is different to the user attempting to use the link. For example, creating the link as the SYS user and then trying to use the link as the AM_ADMIN user.

In this instance either make the link PUBLIC (which all users can then access), or grant the AM_ADMIN user the privileges to create a database link.

Answer (score 3):

According to your screenshot you created the database link as `AM_ADMIN.INT.xxx`. You are calling it without the domain, just as `@AM_ADMIN`. Unless you have a `sqlnet.ora` which defines `names.default_domain` with the same domain value (and have SQL Developer configured to recognise that), you will need to fully-quality the link name when you use it:

```
SELECT * FROM dual@AM_ADMIN.INT.xxx
```

Comment: Hi ALex i am sorry i didnt put the whole part there.
but still i am getting the same error.

Comment: @DeepanshAnand - it gets ORA-02019 with the fully name from the window - if you copy and paste that from the 'edit database link' window? (I think it was obvious `.xxx` was a dummy value and you should use your full real one). Are you running the query as the same user you created the link under - does `select * from all_db_links` show that full name too?

Comment: yes i am running the query as the same user.
and select * from all_db_links shows me the full name.

Comment: When you created the link did you specify the full name or just `AM_ADMIN`? What does `select global_name from global_name` show? Using the full link name should work in any case. I'm afraid I don't understand what you're seeing, unless you just have a typo in the name somewhere.

Comment: While creating the link i specified full name .
the query Select global ___ shows me Global name as ORD853A.INT.XXX
i am not sure what this refers to.
should i include this also in the db link.

Comment: @DeepanshAnand - no, the `.INT.XXX` would have been included in the link name if you hadn't provided it. Assuming the XX part does match what you entered, and are using in your query. Since you're hiding the full name (which is understandable) we can't check if there's a typo, but that's the only thing I can immediately think of.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and I found out that it was a stupid error caused by `(Description = (... HOST = !...)`. When you create Database Link in `USING` clause, you should:

- use the keyword `HOST` if you are using the IP address
- use keyword `HOSTNAME` if you are using the name

I just wanted to share it because I lost half a day trying to figure that out and I couldn't find any information about it...