# Oracle insert command after delete gives error

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I am trying to execute insert command after deleting data from a table but it is giving me an error. I am doing an ACID transaction.

```
<?php
require ( 'conn.conf' );

if ($querydb){
    try {

        //$querydb->beginTransaction();

        $deleteSQL = "delete from THIRD_PARTY_MON";
        $insertSQL = "insert into THIRD_PARTY_MON( select param1, param2 from database@dblink )";

        $parse = oci_parse( $querydb, $deleteSQL );
        oci_execute( $parse, OCI_NO_AUTO_COMMIT );

        $parse = oci_parse( $querydb, $insertSQL );
        oci_execute( $parse , OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS );
        //oci_commit(  $querydb );
    } catch (exception $e){
        oci_rollback( $querydb );
    }
}
?>
```

> PHP Warning:  oci_execute(): ORA-02019: connection description for
>   remote database not found in C:\mon_scripts\third_party.php on line 16
>
> Warning: oci_execute(): ORA-02019: connection description for remote
>   database not found in C:\mon_scripts\third_party.php on line 16

After getting this error if I run a select query, the table `THIRD_PARTY_MON` is empty, so nothing was inserted into it.

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: are you using a db link

Comment: yes db link is being used in insert query

Comment: check this SO question if it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39270446/ora-02019-connection-description-for-remote-database-not-found

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure out there was an error in the insert query i was using.